# ¿Cómo puedo integrar SonarQube Quality Gate en mi pipeline de Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Estoy ejecutando en un pipeline un comando para que le pase el sonar a un proyecto, lo que necesito es que, al igual que en un job normal se queda el enlace del sonar una vez ejecutado el job, pase lo mismo en el pipeline, ya que cuando lo ejecuto en el pipeline, no se me guarda el enlace de SonarQube, así tengo los steps en groovy:

```
stage ('QA'){
                steps { 
                    echo 'executing sonar'
                    bat  'mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url='+env.SONAR_URL+' -Dsonar.projectName=QA:%JOB_BASE_NAME% -Dsonar.projectKey=QA:%JOB_BASE_NAME%'
                }
            }

            stage("Quality Gate"){
                timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
                    def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv
                    if (qg.status != 'OK') {
                        error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Allí estás usando el plugin de Maven para la ejecución del sonarqube. Instala el plugin de Jenkins y puedes seguir este resumen:

- Configuras el servidor de sonarqube en Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > SonarQube Scanner
- En el pipeline colocas este código:

```
    stage('Sonarqube') {
        environment {
            scannerHome = tool 'SonarQubeScanner'
        }
        steps {
            withSonarQubeEnv('sonarqube') {
                sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
            }
            timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
            }
        }
    }
```

Esto lo obtuve en:
https://medium.com/@rosaniline/setup-sonarqube-with-jenkins-declarative-pipeline-75bccdc9075f

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/171989)

Comment: Gracias por la correción

Comment: De nada, si tu respuesta es aceptada paso a regalarte un voto positivo.